# TCPDUMP Missing response Code header in Back to back execution

Tags: tcpdump, wireshark

I am running two TCPDUMP Commands back to back. Here is the sequence

1. Run the below command

   `root@open5Gs:/home/test# tcpdump -l -vvv -s0 -i any -B 4096 -nn -w  /home/test/tc060.pcap -c 1500`
2. Execute Test Case
3. Wait until tcpdump completes packet capture

```
root@open5Gs:/home/test# tcpdump -l -vvv -s0 -i any -B 4096 -nn -w  /home/test/tc060.pcap -c 1500
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
1500 packets captured
2588 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

4. Execute command for Next Packet capture

`tcpdump -l -vvv -s0 -i any -B 4096 -nn -w  /home/test/tc078.pcap -c 1500`

and repeat steps 1 to 3

The Problem I am seeing is as soon as back to back tcpdump command is run for the 2nd  PCAP response code is not captured.

[image: No Response Code available]

But If I wait for some time after execution completion of first tcpdump and rerun the 2nd tcpdump command. I can see the response code

[image]

Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening? Why 2nd TCPDUMP command expecting a delay post execution of 1st tcpdump command execution

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated.